# How to deploy an ad-hoc distribution (ipa file) or how to synchronize iTunes with devices

Tags: iphone, synchronization, itunes, distribution, adhoc

I'm using the Ad-Hoc distribution to deploy my app on different devices. I already created an *.ipa file and dragged it onto iTunes. Under "Apps" I selected my app and dragged it onto the device. This worked only one time.

Now if I try it again a **red serrated circle with a one** in it appears when dragging the app onto the device. What I'm doing wrong?

I have to add that the Mac I'm using is also the development machine. I also tried to replace the *.ipa file but it is the same result. I tried it on different devices. It is always the same problem ...

**Edit:**
On iPad with iOS 4.2.1 it worked one time. On another iPad (same capabilities but also with iOS 4.2.1) it does not. So upgrading to a newer iOS on other devices should not be relevant. I'll try the zip + mobileprovision method.

**No**

Perhaps the problem is that the first synchronization tooks place on another computer (Apple uses the binding between iTunes and the computer) and not the one I'm using.

Comment: Where does the red badge icon appear?

Comment: On the mini file symbol always near the mouse pointer (holding the mouse and dragging the app icon).

Comment: This most likely has to do with sync settings: if you set the iPad to manual sync, you can drag apps (and media) files directly to it, otherwise, they will be synced automatically according to your sync settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the problem:

1. Select your device in iTunes
2. Click on "Apps" on the top (where music, pictures etc is)
3. Activate "Synchronize apps"
4. Confirm the synchronization of apps
5. Select the app
6. Click on "Apply" (on the right bottom)

Comment: The procedure is changed for NEW XCODE 4.5 & iTunes versions

Comment: Which is what exactly Abhishek?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Xcode v9.2 (when developing for iOS 11)**

After you have built your application and completed the 'Archive for Publishing' process you can deploy your Ad Hoc app using Xcode v9.2, *including apps built for publishing using Visual Studio for Macs.*

---

*The steps in Xcode to deploy adhoc apps (e.g. an .ipa file):*

1.) Connect phone to Mac.

2.) Choose the **Window** menu and select **Devices and Simulators**.

3.) On the left-hand sidebar titled **Connected**, choose the device you want to deploy the app too.

4.) On the right-hand side will appear the details of the device you selected. This will include a list titled **INSTALLED APPS** (e.g. list of non-AppStore apps installed on the device). At the bottom of that list, hit the **+** (plus) icon to add an app.

5.) Using the 'Finder' dialog that appears, navigate to the .ipa file on your hard drive. Highlight that file and click the **Open** button.

These steps result in an iOS app, if built using an Ad Hoc distribution provisioning profile, being loaded on your iOS device.